# How to show the whole table

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have this code

```
mat = ( {
    {7, 6},
    {2, 4}
   } );
Print[" Min ", 
 Grid[{Min /@ mat}, 
  Background -> {Automatic, 
    Automatic, {{1, 1} -> Red, {1, 2} -> Red}}, ItemSize -> {2, 1}, 
  Frame -> All]]
```

However it displays only two cells that are the minimum of each row. How can I make the other numbers appear in the table, but only the minimum to be in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Row@{
  "Min ",
  Grid[
   mat,
   Background -> {
     Automatic,
     Automatic,
     Table[
      {n, First@Ordering[mat[[n]]]} -> Red,
      {n, Length@mat}
      ]
     },
   Frame -> All,
   ItemSize -> {2, 1}
   ]
  }
```

[image]

We build the list of rules for the red cells by going over each row using `Table`. The index of the minimal element of each row can be found using [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html)

Here the same thing for the maximum in each column:

```
Row@{
  "Max ",
  Grid[
   mat,
   Background -> {
     Automatic,
     Automatic,
     Table[
      {Last@Ordering[mat[[All, n]]], n} -> Green,
      {n, Length@mat[[1]]}
      ]
     },
   Frame -> All,
   ItemSize -> {2, 1}
   ]
  }
```

[image]

A few things changed:

- We iterate over the columns of the matrix now.

  - Therefore, `Table` goes over the length in the second dimension.
  - We need to look at the elements per column, so `mat[[All,n]]` instead of `mat[[n]]`.
  - The indices of the position specifications were also flipped
- Since we're looking for the maximum, we take the `Last` element of the list returned by `Ordering`.

Comment: Thank you, by finding the maximum in each pillar what should I replace?I think row with column,but I am not sure for the others.

Comment: @M.Alexis I've added a second example

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
{{7, 6}, {2, 4}} //
  ReplaceAll[v_?VectorQ :> (v /. Min[v] -> Item[Min[v], Background -> Red])] // 
Legended[Grid[#, Dividers -> All], SwatchLegend[{Red}, {"minimum"}]] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]